# How can I use promises to call this function asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, promise, q

I'm trying to create a parse.com function that checks the database for a record and creates a new one or returns the existing one if it exists. I want to do this asynchronously and I'm attempting to use promises (q i suppose ). The syntax is confusing me a bit, this is what i tried but it's trowing the error "Cannot call method 'then' of undefined" how would I write this as a proper promise.

```
  function createPersonIfDoesNotExist(personName)
  {
    var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
    var personQuery = new Parse.Query(Person);
    personQuery.equalTo("Name", personName);
    personQuery.find({
      success: function(results) {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " person.");
        if(results.length >0){
          console.log("Looks like this person exists already, no point it making a new one");
          var artist =  results[0];
          return artist;
        }
        else
        {
          // Create a new Person
          var person = new Person();
          return person;
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        return error;
      }
    });
  }

  var promise = createPersonIfDoesNotExist(personname);
  promise.then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: There seem to be two problems - your function is called `createPersonIfDoesNotExist` but you are calling `createArtistIfDoesNotExist`. Also, your function does not return anything. If `personQuery.find()` is the function that creates a promise, you need to return that.

Comment: No reason to use Q, Parse already ships with its own promise implementation. Just try not to use `success` and `error` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The OP code doesn't return anything.  What it should return is the promise generated by the parse find() or save() methods.

It becomes easier to read and maintain if you write small functions that create small, value-add promises over the parse promise-returning functions...

```
// return a promise that is fulfilled with a new Person with the given name
function createPersonNamed(personName) {
    var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
    var person = new Person();
    person.set("Name", personName);
    return person.save();
}

// return a promise that is fulfilled with the first existing person with a given name
function findPersonNamed(personName) {
    var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
    var personQuery = new Parse.Query(Person);
    personQuery.equalTo("Name", personName);
    return personQuery.first();
}

// return a promise that is fulfilled with either an existing person with a given name,
// or a newly created one if the Person does not exist
function findOrCreatePersonNamed(personName) {
    return findPersonNamed(personName).then(function(person) {
        return (person)? person : createPersonNamed(personName);
    });
}
```